# Path for mounted iso

Tags: mount

I need to access my mounted iso in terminal but where it is mounted? My partitions used to mount in `/media`

What are the general paths for where different things are mounted?

**Edit**: I mounted my ISO by just double clicking it (Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `~/.gvfs/` as that's where gnome tends to mount things.

Comment: Great! Its there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in Lubuntu, using Furius iso mounter, the path was `/home/user/isofilename_ISO`. Using AcetoneISO, the path was `/home/user/virtual-drives/1`. In case the mount point is not automatically accessed, Acetone can be set to do that: go to File/Options/General options/File manager and select file browser (e.g., Thunar or Nautilus, after having installed them: in Lubuntu/LXDE I do not recommend Nautilus, but Thunar; selecting LXDE in that list seems useless).
[image]