# Where is my mounted iso if not in `/media` nor in `~/.gvfs/`?

Tags: 12.04, mount, lubuntu, iso, paths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Path for mounted iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29433/path-for-mounted-iso)
>   [How can I graphically mount ISOs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43469/how-can-i-graphically-mount-isos)

I have mounted an iso with Furius ISO Mount Tool.

Now: **I cannot see it in `/media`  or in  `~/.gvfs/`** (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/29435/47206) - please do not mark as clone before I get a solution here: because the other question received that very specific and definitive answer that is not good for me and would not get new answers, which I am asking here for)

Comment: please avoid cluttering the website with duplicate content - if you want to draw attention to an existing question, you may [offer a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: @Takkat: As I am not asking "how can i mount" but where is the mount point, my question is not a clone to the one you mention but formally to the other one (link in my question). It is there that I should add my answers as you said, and I did. In fact after that this one should be closed

Comment: @cipricus: yeah, I did realize this. However with Furius it is you who defines the mount point. This was not too clear from the existing answer. Thank you for taking your time to make our content better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in the lower part of its window, Furius ISO specifies the path to the mounted iso, something like: `home/user/isofilename_ISO`. Mounting with Acetoneiso the mount point is `/home/user/virtual-drives/1`. Not opening automatically the iso content seems relatedd to Lubuntu and pcmanfm. As Furius has no options to set, better use Acetone iso: it can be set to open iso content in Thunar automatically: [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/218440/47206).

Comment: this is my definitive answer now, and so the question may be closed: as it is formally a clone of http://askubuntu.com/a/29435/47206, question that will stay open